# MongoDB - Insert a document in a collection but it has elements from other collection

Tags: json, mongodb, insert

I have 3 collections: employee, address (employee's home address) and workplace. An employee document references a workplace and address document. I want to insert a document into the employee collection. However, in my employee collection, I have two columns that one is referring to the address_id and one is referring to workplace_id.

The new employee info is:

- First Name: Jake
- Last Name: Sample
- Email: jakesample@email.com
- Age: 26
- Interest: Biking, Hiking

And this employee's workplace and address are already in the other 2 collections, let's say that in workplace collection, the workplace_id is "aaaaa" and in the address collection, the address_id is "bbbbb".

How can I insert this new document into my employee collection with the already existed workplace_id and address_id?

Here is what I have:

```
db.employee.insert_one({
    "firstname": "Jake",
    "lastname": "Sample",
    "email": "jakesample@email.com",
    "age": "26",
    "interests": ["Biking", "Hiking"],
    "address_id": ObjectId("bbbbb"),
    "workplace_id": ObjectId("aaaaa"),
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables to store the values you want from another documents.

```
var emp_address_id = db.address.find({"id": ObjectId("bbbbb")});
var emp_workplace_id = db.workplace.find({"id": ObjectId("aaaaa")});

db.employee.insert_one({
     "firstname": "Jake",
     "lastname": "Sample",
     "email": "jakesample@email.com",
     "age": "26",
     "interests": ["Biking", "Hiking"],
     "address_id": emp_address_id,
     "workplace_id": emp_workplace_id
})
```